# C# Find the newest created *.txt file in specified directory AND sub-directories?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, file-io, path-finding

I have now tried everything but something is not working:

I need to find the newest Date Created *.txt file in my specified directory and sub-directories.

```
string tPath = "C:\MyDirectory";
string[] fDir = Directory.GetFiles(tPath, "*.txt",  SearchOption.AllDirectories); 
filePath = fDir[0];
```

Adding, the following leads to and compilation error:

```
string[] fDir = Directory.GetFiles(tPath, "*.txt",  SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
```

Error CS1061 'string' does not contain a definition for 'LastWriteTime' and no extension method 'LastWriteTime' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Im out of ideas, please help

Comment: Typo: *txt, it should be *.txt

Comment: sorry its correct on my actual code, just a typo on the website,

Comment: You need to pull in FileInfo objects, not just the filenames: `FileInfo[] fInf = Directory.GetFiles(tPath, "*.txt",  SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                       .Select(x=>new FileInfo(x)).ToArray(); 
            
`

Comment: Maybe just use FileInfo instead of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Directory.GetFiles()` is wildly inefficient for enumerating file system objects. `Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries()` does the same job in a significantly more optimal way.

Next, what `GetFiles()` (and `EnumerateFileSystemEntries()`, for that matter) return is a collection of full paths to file system objects, which is why your second snippet is failing to compile. Try something like

```
foreach(var fileInfo in Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries().Select(s => new FileInfo(s))
```

This might fail too (permissions, `EnumerateFileSystemEntries()` returning directory paths, etc.), but will get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, actually found the answer to my own question:

```
string tPath = "C:\MyDirectory";
filePath = Directory.EnumerateFiles(tPath, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(File.GetCreationTime).First();
```

the difference was: 
`OrderByDescending(File.GetCreationTime).First()`

NOT `OrderByDescending(f => f.GetCreationTime).First()`

ps thanks for the tip about .enumeratefiles